# iOS NavigationLink with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, swiftui, expo, react-navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using NativeStack from React Navigation with React Native Expo, and I was wondering how I can create something like this, with the NavigationLink inside a list.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    private var bgColors: [Color] = [ .indigo, .yellow, .green, .orange, .brown ]

    var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            List(bgColors, id: \.self) { bgColor in
                NavigationLink {
                    bgColor
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                } label: {
                    Text(bgColor.description)
                }

            }
            .listStyle(.plain)

            .navigationTitle("Color")
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

I've tried using the Link component from Expo and the Button component from React native, but they don't seem to produce the same smooth animation as the NavigationLink from SwiftUI.